# webpack-dev-server Cannot find module 'webpack'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to use webpack-dev-server to run a simple program
but I'm getting this error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I have installed webpack with following npm command

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

and I have the following configuration:

```
(webpack.config.js)
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/app');

var config = {
  entery: APP_DIR + '/index.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle,js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I have tried everything and I'm really lost.
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: how do you run your code? Please share cmd line

Comment: `entery` has a typo it should be `entry` (if that was copied directly from the webpack config)

Comment: If someone is looking for an up to date Webpack 5 tutorial, check out this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-setup-tutorial/

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`npm install --save-dev webpack` is not enough.

You also have to install the following:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

And optionally, you can also install:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-middleware webpack-hot-middleware
```

Comment: i have reinstalled the webpack and the webpack-dev-server and it worked thanks!

Comment: You are Welcome .. Try also to use `npm run build` instead of `npm build` and `npm run xxx` instead of `npm xxx` .. so on.

Comment: When running the first line, I get the error : operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\node_modules

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, but I resolved by installing additional `webpack-cli`

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

Firstly, you need to install webpack-dev-server

`npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server`

Then in your package.json, use this in your start script:

`"start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open"`

Note `webpack.config.js` should be replaced with the file name of your webpack config file.

Now run `npm start`

Hope it works!